# Getting invalid syntax on function definition

Tags: python

```
def create_processor_groups(self, parent_id=None, name: str=None, position: tuple=(0, 0)):
```

I have this function definition and it gives me invalid syntax on name and position. If I remove the types, the error goes but this should also work. What is wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Type hints only arrived with 3.5, I think

Comment: You are using ":" inside a tuple () which is not allowed, you may need to define a Dictionary outside your function and parse it within your function. In case you may call it multiple time you may use Class instead.

Comment: Your line does not throw an error on my version of Python -- 3.5.3 -- which ***strongly*** suggests your version is too old for this syntax.

Comment: strange, I had 3.6 selected as the default interpreter but It somehow isn't accepting it properly. But if i give it 2.7 it generates venv for 2.7. and then the error is understandable but its still not taking 3.6

Comment: Just tried your function definition in Python 3.7 and it works, no problem. I think you should double-check your environnement, you could be using a different version of Python unknowingly. You can run the following inside the same environnement:

`import sys`
`print(sys.version)`

and report the results

Comment: I have 3.6 selected as the interpreter in the project settings in pycharm but sys.version is showing 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing code in Python 2.7 which can throw error. Python 3.x should run your code.

Comment: It is a new feature in python 3.x  that it uses colon to specify argument type.

Comment: Note: I believe it is only Python versions >= 3.5 that has typing support. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: strange, I had 3.6 selected as the default interpreter but It somehow isn't accepting it properly. But if I give it 2.7 it generates venv for 2.7. and then the error is understandable but its still not taking 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Sam.
I've got the error Unexpected EOF while parsing,when executed yout code. That means your code end is reached before the end of a block.
You should put something after (inside) your declaration like

`def create_processor_groups(self, parent_id=None, name: str=None, position: tuple=(0, 0)):
    print('something')`

Comment: That is not the error that Sam reports and so it does not seem to be the problem. He only omitted the next lines of code in his post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any immediate reason why your code is not working so **the most likely issue is that you are using a Python version < 3.5.**

Another potential issue could be that lack of any code in the body of the function causing an EOF error as mentioned in another answer (though I will assume you just haven't included this in the question because you didn't think it was relevant). **Note that it's always best to include a minimal but complete example in your *stackoverflow* questions.**

In Python 3.5.1, using an integer argument works as expected:

```
def dostuff(a: int):
  return 2*a

dostuff(1)
2
```

So does using a tuple:

```
def domore(a: tuple):
  return a[0]

domore((3,5))
3
```

But for tuples where the contained type is known, which may be your case, it may be better (stricter) to use a type alias, as follows:

```
from typing import Tuple

TINT = Tuple[int]

def docoolstuff(a: TINT):
  return sum(a)

docoolstuff((1, 2, 3))
6
```

If you can't upgrade your Python version for any reason, there may be other packages which provide type hints in lower versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code : (this will show you the version of Python you're actually using)

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If the reported Python version is somehow < 3.5 then you should investigate your environment first and use the correct intended version.

Comment: I have 3.6 selected as the interpreter in the project settings in pycharm but sys.version is showing 2.7 –

Comment: which python and which python3 gives me the location so the location is correct.

Comment: Then there's something amiss, did you run the above code from inside pycharm ?

Comment: np. It worked after I restarted the IDE :D somehow it was not taking 3.6 as default i changed it and did it per project and finally had to restart

Comment: Sadly, I don't use Pycharm, but surely there's a problem with your setup, i think you should reinstall something, but not sure which is it. Hope that helps

Comment: That's great then. But you need to identify the root cause so you don't get stuck again. Good luck.

Comment: yes, true. It recommends making a per project config rather than a global. I hadnt set a per project config. and after setting I didnt not restarted the IDE.

Comment: That's great, In case this answer helped you out, you might as well select it as an answer to your question.